# How Do I edit the Value of a Text Box?

Tags: javascript, console, edit

There is a text box value that I want to edit using a console in my web browser. I have the element using this code:

```
epic = document.querySelector('[name = "channel_name"]');
```

now I want to edit the value of the text box. Things like this:

```
epic.value = "yes";
epic.textContent = "yes";
epic.innerHTML = "yes";
```

do nothing.
I would also like to know how to enter it when I have entered the value.

Comment: I used ```epic.textContent = "yes"``` on the element next to it that actually had the text I wanted to edit in it. The text changed, but if you click on the text box it goes back to the previous text, then when you click elsewhere the text goes back to yes. I think this is because the input isn't changed, the literal visual is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. Executing the code below at the console changes the search textbox at the top of this page:

```
document.querySelector('[name = "q"]').value = 'yes';
```